# How to run Dataflow Job from pipeline.pb file

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run Custom Template in Google Cloud Dataflow and I think I faced an error in documentation or something like that, but I am not sure. I would like to ask if I correctly do steps to run custom template on Dataflow and how to fix it.

I wrote my apache_beam file in Python and using this command: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#create-and-stage-a-classic-template

I tried to convert my python file into a template with that command from above link because Dataflow requires JSON file instead of python. This last command to create template created following files:

- apache_beam-2.49.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
- dataflow_python_sdk.tar
- pipeline.pb

I don't see any JSON file here, so I tried providing pipeline.pb because documentation says that I need to provide template file(https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#custom-templates). However it says that JSON file is required and it ends with error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '�', " �� � )re"... is not valid JSON
```

I tried providing this file both to Job and Pipeline creation windows, but both of these want JSON files and end with the same errors.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how did you create this file? pipeline.pb file

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like I messed up paths. My bad.
So for anyone hitting the same problem in the future, there are important things:

- staging_location argument when creating a template is a directory where dataflow and apache_beam related files will be uploaded to. These files are not to be touched, they just need to exist.
- template_location is a path where JSON template FILE will be created. It's not a directory path, it's the full path of the final template file, so remember about naming it correctly so it's not lost somewhere. This is the file that Dataflow wants to create your pipeline.